# how to find code for model no of iphone

Tags: iphone

model no of iphone through code

Answer (score 3):

```
UIDevice *myCurrentDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];  

NSLog(@"%@", [myCurrentDevice model]);
NSLog(@"%@", [myCurrentDevice systemName]);
NSLog(@"%@", [myCurrentDevice systemVersion]);
```

// result

iPhone
iPhone OS
3.1.2